# PHP Carbon - How to compare a Datetime by minutes without seconds?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php-carbon

I have a query to get the bookings that were done on a specific date which is run by a cronjob (every minute). However,  I cannot seem to query bookings rounded off to the nearest minute. How can this be achieved?

`Booking::where('completed_at', now())->get();`

This query only allows to compare

***Y-m-d H:i:s***

How can I compare

***Y-m-d H:i***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two solutions that come to mind:

```
Booking::whereBetween('completed_at', [now()->startOfMinute(), now()->endOfMinute() ])->get();
```

This gets everything within the same minute

```
Booking::where(\DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(completed_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')"), now()->format('Y-m-d H:i'))->get();
```

This matches formatted dates.

I prefer the 1st approach because you don't need to worry about formatting issues and it can also make use of indexes.

Comment: Be careful, cronjob can't be 100% accurate in the timing and the PHP process itself is not instant, you can have 1 run at 12:00:59.99 and next run at 12:02:00.01, it's ~1 minute interval and fine regarding cronjob but you actually miss the timecode 12:01

Answer (score 1):

Asserting that `now()` will happen exactly every 60.00 seconds is wrong, cronjob run every 60 seconds +/- few ms, and PHP process before calling `now()` (and between 2 calls of `now()`) takes few µs to few ms depending on the operations.

So you should have a field like `processed_by_the_cronjob` which is `false` by default and you set it to `true` once your CRON job queried it.

Then you select:

```php
Booking::where('completed_at', '<=', now())->andWhere('processed_by_the_cronjob', false)->get();
```

Else, once in a while you'll have booking that will get skipped.